# Scheduler program using python

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, subprocess, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a simple scheduler on the machine that I share with my colleague. The idea is to run a process in the background as a server, identified by its pid. I can submit the program I want to run to this server process, say in a different bash terminal, and let the server process schedule the job regarding the availability of the hardware resource. The submit program should be able to lock some content in memory and communicate with the server.

I was trying to use python multiprocessing or subprocess module to do the above thing. But I didn't have a clear idea how this should be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you want `batch`?

Answer (score 0):

I think [cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) or [`celery`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) would be a better choice for you use case. Just create the celery task and delay its execution according to your needs.